# Mean Value Property From Brownian Motion

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

Let $B_t$ $(t \geq 0)$ be a Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}^3$. That is, $B_t = (B_{t}^{(1)},B_{t}^{(2)},B_{t}^{(3)})$, where each $B_{t}^{(i)}$ is a Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $D$ be a open, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $E$ be the complement of $D$. Define the function $f$ by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{E} \frac{1}{|x-y|} dy.
$$

I am being asked to show that $f$ has the mean value property. I think I am supposed to use that
$$
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} I({\{t:B_t \in E\}})(t)dt \right) = f(B_0),
$$
where $I(A)$ denotes the indicator function of the set $A$. I was helped with proving this here: [An Integral Involving Brownian Motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317592/an-integral-involving-brownian-motion)

Explicitly, I need to show 
$$
f(z) = \int_{\partial B_r(z)} f(x) d\mu(x)
$$
for any ball $B_r(z) \subset D$, where $\mu$ is the uniform measure on $\partial B_r(z)$.

I know that

My idea is to observe that when $B_0 = z$ and $\tau = \inf\{ t \geq 0 : B_t \text{ exits } B_r(z)\}$, $B_\tau$ is uniformly distributed on $\partial B_r(z)$ and
$$
\int_{\partial B_r(z)} f(x) d\mu(x) = \mathbb{E}f(B_t).
$$
With this observation and the fact which I think I am supposed to use, I am reduced to showing that 
$$
\mathbb{E}f(B_t) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} I({\{t:B_t \in E\}})(t)dt \right).
$$

I'm stuck on proving the last part. I would appreciate any help. Is this even the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $f(x)$ is always finite (it is possible to have $f(x)=+\infty$ for some $x$, in which case $f(x)=+\infty$ everywhere.)

Let $B_t^x$  be  Brownian motion with $B_0^x=x$.  Then the idea is that, as you proved already,
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(z)&=&
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} I({\{u:B^z_u \in E\}})(t)\, dt \right)\\
&=& \mathbb{E} \left(\int_{\tau}^{\infty} I({\{u:B^z_u \in E\}})(t)\, dt \right),
\end{eqnarray*}
since the motion stays in $B_r(z)\subset D$ until time $\tau$
$$=
\mathbb{E} \left( \mathbb{E} \left(\int_{\tau}^{\infty} I({\{u:B^z_u \in E\}})(t)\,dt  \Bigg| B^z_\tau \right) \right).
$$
Then by the strong Markov property of Brownian motion,
$$
\mathbb{E} \left(\int_{\tau}^{\infty} I({\{u:B^z_u \in E\}})(t)\,dt  \Bigg| B^z_\tau \right)=f(B^z_\tau)
$$
and the problem should then be completed as you suggested above.